# Why PHP form Handling Not Working

Tags: php, html, forms

I followed [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) and created a form like bellow in my gen.php . I want to generate post by imputing information and I will copy and pest the generated html from textarea of gen-res.php.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Text Generator</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="gen-res.php" method="post" id="generator">
App Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
App ID: <input type="text" name="id"><br>
Intro text:<textarea name="intro" form="generator"></textarea>
Features:
<textarea name="feature" form="generator">
<ol>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ol></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Generate">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

And my gen.php is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Epdroid App Generator</title>
</head>
<body>

Generated!
<textarea><div> <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?> </div> <div> <?php echo $_GET["intro"]; ?> </div> <div> ID:  <?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?> </div> <?php echo $_GET["feature"]; ?> </textarea>


</body>
</html>
```

But the output is

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Epdroid App Generator</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    Generated!
    <textarea><div></div> <div> </div> <div> ID:   </div>  </textarea>


    </body>
 </html>
```

So, Why this is not working and the variables are not passing?

Comment: you need to have server link wamp installed in your server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are sending your data via POST but you are trying to get your data via $_GET.

Change all of your $_GET to $_POST and it will probably work.

Example

`<textarea><div> <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to change form method to get like this:

```
<form action="gen-res.php" method="GET" id="generator">
```